# The word "Fighting" to give encouragement

Tags: meaning, word-usage

We Chinese people used to say "fighting" to give encouragement like "Good luck" or "Keep it up". I just talked with a foreigner he seems didn't understand what I said. So, is this word not commonly used or is it a correct word I using it?

Comment: Do you mean you say the single word ***Fighting*** to give encouragement? It sounds a bit like the French ***bon courage*** - literally "good courage", but does not translate readily into English.

Comment: To directly answer your question as a BE speaker, no, I don't think I've ever heard "fighting" used like this.

Comment: "Fighting", by itself, would not be recognized as a term of encouragement by most USAians.  "Fighting" is, however, an idiom in a number of other contexts.

Comment: @WS2 yes to give encouragement.

Comment: The closest I can think of is *hang in there* or *keep on keepin' on*. If you wanted to coin something similar but with the stronger meaning of fighting, it would likely be *Fight!* or *Fight back!* (exhorting the person to fight), not *fighting*. - La luta continua...

Comment: "*Keep up the good fight*" sounds close.

Comment: Can you point to some contexts where Chinese people give encouragement by saying, "Fighting"? If this was in the past (*cf* your "used to say"), please indicate what period and which region.

Comment: @Lawrence  usually used in Korea especially I can hear on some TV show like running man, (maybe Japan as well, I don't know) and China also use so. Actually I don't know what's the orgin of "fighting" which given such meaning.

Comment: It's coming from the saying fighting spirit, to encourage before entering a combat, to embrace yourself and your mind to spiritually get ready to an obstacle coming your way. Equivalent to the word 加油 in Chinese.

Comment: In your culture, is the Chinese language equivalent for “fighting” used this way?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like *"Hang in there"* might be the closest English equivalent. As in "hang in there, keep *fighting*, don't give up".

> hang in there - said as a way of telling someone to not give up, despite difficulties:
>   Work can get tough in the middle of a term but hang in there and it'll be OK.

[Hang in there - Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hang-in-there)

Answer (score 0):

Japanese has the same idiom, among many other peculiar usages of loaned English.

So yes, it's a Chinese adaptation, and would not be immediately understood by native English-only speakers.